# Why is my submenu system in JavaScript for not opening properly?

Tags: javascript, html, touch, getelementbyid, classname

In the below example HTML I've optimised my website to, dependent on what operating system the javascript code detects, to dynamically change the layout of the website.
The Desktop version of the website works fine. The only problem that I have is that when opening the navigation menu for the Mobile version of the website it screws up its layout.

When the menu navigation bar is opened it layout displays like that in the 1st picture.

But it's suppose to look like the second picture.

I've narrowed the offending code to:

**var box1 = document.getElementById('box1').className = "OPEN_topmenu OPEN_submenu";**

The above code in bold screws up the layout when opening the menu on mobile device but without it the navigation bar would not open the submenus. The help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>HOME</title>
</head>
<body onload="load_style()"> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script>
function MOBILE_LAYOUT() {
    if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Android") != -1) {
        var mobile = document.createElement("link");
        mobile.rel = "stylesheet";
        mobile.type = "text/css";
        mobile.media = "all";
        mobile.href = "../mobileSTYLE.css";
        console.log("MOBILE LAYOUT CSS loaded.");

        document.head.appendChild(mobile);
        document.getElementById("MOBILE").innerHTML;
    }
}

function DESKTOP_LAYOUT() {
    if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Mac") != -1) {
        var desktop = document.createElement("link");
        desktop.rel = "stylesheet";
        desktop.type = "text/css";
        desktop.media = "all";
        desktop.href = "../DESKTOPstyle.css";
        console.log("DESKTOP LAYOUT CSS loaded.");

        document.head.appendChild(desktop);
        document.getElementById("DESKTOP").innerHTML;
    }
}
    
function load_style() {
    DESKTOP_LAYOUT();
    MOBILE_LAYOUT();
}

window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    var box1 = document.getElementById('box1')
    var startx = 0
    var dist = 0
    
    box1.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){
    
        var touchobj = e.changedTouches[0]
        startx = parseInt(touchobj.clientX)
        var box1 = document.getElementById('box1').className = "OPEN_topmenu OPEN_submenu";
    }, false)
    
    box1.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){ 

        var touchobj = e.changedTouches[0]
        var dist = parseInt(touchobj.clientX) - startx
        if (e.cancelable) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        
    }, false)
    
    box1.addEventListener('touchend', function(e){
    
        var touchobj = e.changedTouches[0]
        e.preventDefault()
    }, false)
    
}, false)
</script>

<div id="DESKTOP">
<div id="WEBSITEbanner">
  <h1>HOME</h1>
</div>
<ul class="topmenu">
  <li class="submenu"><a href="../Art_Work.html"><b>Game
        Art Work</b></a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="../Game_Art_Work.html#Monkey">
          Monkey</a></li>
      <li><a href="../Game_Art_Work.html#3D_Work">3D
          Work</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Cztery</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="submenu"><a href="../Games.html"><b>Games</b></a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">szesc</a></li>
      <li><a href="">siedem</a></li>
      <li><a href="">osiem</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="submenu"><a href="../Games_D.html"><b>Game
        D</b></a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">dziesiec</a></li>
      <li><a href="">jedenascie</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<div id="center">
  <div id="Services">
    <center>
      <h1><a name="#3D_Work">About Me</a></h1>
    </center>
    Hi,
    <p></p>
    Welcome to the website.
    <p></p>
    Welcome Description </div>
</div>

</div>
<p></p>
<div id="footer">
  <h3>Footer</h3>
</div>
</div>
<div id="MOBILE">
<div id="Hometitle">
  <h1>HOME</h1>
</div>
<ul class="closedMENU closedsubmenu" id="box1">
  <div id="MENU_heading_HIDDEN">Menu </div>
  <li id="MENU_heading_HIDDEN"><br>
    <a href="../Game_Art_Work.html">Game
      Art Work</a></li>
  <li id="MENU_heading_HIDDEN"><br>
    <a href="../Games.html">Games</a></li>
  <li id="MENU_heading_HIDDEN"><br>
    <a href="../Games_D.html">Game
      D</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="BLOG_ARTICLE_1">
  <div id="BLOGtitle"> Hi,<br>
    Welcome to the website.<br>
    <br>
    Welcome Description</div>
</div>
<br>
<div id="BLOG_ARTICLE_1">
  <div id="BLOGtitle">Footer </div>
</div>
<br>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Menu Navigation Bar Layout Not Correct]

[image: Menu Navigation Bar Layout Correct]

Comment: Please remove the android tag as it is related to mobile phones but not android

Comment: I don't think there is any way to fix this without more info. Please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and **verifiable** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Get rid of stuff that works and leave stuff that doesn't, including HTML, CSS and JS.

Comment: All of the code is relevant because if you exclude the code that generates the Desktop version of the website. The Mobile version will work.